# Which are the unused digital pins after L293D motor shield is installed on a Arduino Uno board?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have just started my first project on Arduino. I have an Arduino Uno and an L293D motor shield.

I have installed the motor shield on the Arduino Uno board and the motor shield covers all pins of the Arduino Uno board. The motor shield is connected with four gear motors and one servo motor.

Can I use digital pins 2-13 to make some LED flashing circuit?

Which digital pins are used by the Motor shield and which pins are not used?

---

It is L293D motor shield. A0 and A5 are used in the code. Four DC motors and one servo motor is used.

Comment: Link to the shield? Is it really a L29D, or is it actually a L293D? What pins are used in the code?

Comment: @MatsK, I notice in your edit you removed `tt` from gear motor description. It looks like this is a brand/model. See here: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3777. I didn't know what it meant at first either so I had left it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the same board as seen on [Banggood](https://uk.banggood.com/Motor-Driver-Shield-L293D-Duemilanove-Mega-U-NO-p-72855.html) Which may also be seen at [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield)
The schematic shows most of the digital pins in use

```
D3  - PWM2B  
D4  - DIR_CLK  
D5  - PWM0B  
D6  - PWM0A  
D7  - DIR_EN  
D8  - DIR_SER  
D9  - PWM1A  
D10 - PWM1B  
D11 - PWM2A  
D12 - DIR_LATCH
```

The analogue pins A0-A5 are still free - these can be used as digital pins.